# Unable to move metadata of one column with Copy/Move option of Modern SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, move, modern-document-library, modern

I Created Archive library from Main library and using Copy/Move option to move/copy documents from one library to other with Metadata.
All metadata and document is getting moved/copied only data from one column is missing. Not sure what I am missing.
Column is single line of text.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the same list schema in the target library.

If the issue appears in the same list schema, please try to restore a earlier version that contains the missing column value and copy to/Move to again to compare the result.